# Name of Foreign Key EF6

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My entity has a `List<SecondEntityDTO>`. When EF generates the table, in the table `SecondEntities` there's a column name `FirstEntityDTO_id`. I would like this column to be named "ParentEntity_id". How can I do that?

I tried annotating the List of `SecondEntityDTO` and a bunch of other things...

**Edit1:** I belive you guys missunderstood.
This is my MainEntity:

```
[Table("MainEntities")]
public class MainEntityDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<SubEntityDTO> SubEntities { get; set; }
}
```

This is `SubEntityDTO`:

```
[Table("SubEntities")]
public class SubEntityDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {            
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MainEntities",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.SubEntities",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    MainEntityDTO_id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MainEntities", t => t.MainEntityDTO_id)
            .Index(t => t.MainEntityDTO_id);
    }
```

Note the name of the third column on the `SubEntities` table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can do the same using [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx), for example, overwritting the `OnModelCreating` method of your Context and doing this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<SecondEntity>().Property(s => s.FirstEntityDTO_id).HasColumnName("ParentEntity_id");
}
```

### Update

Why you don't edit Func<> that specifies the columns of that table. As you can see you are creating  an anonymous type, so you can change the name of the column there, eg:

```
 CreateTable(
            "dbo.SubEntities",
            c => new
            {
                id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Title = c.String(),
                ParentEntity_id = c.Int(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MainEntities", t => t.ParentEntity_id)
            .Index(t => t.ParentEntity_id);
```

If you do this, remember change the name of that property in the `Down` method, but if you already executed that script, don't change the  FK name yet in the `Down` method. Execute again the `Update Database` command specifying the name of that script. That will drop those tables and they will be created once again using the `Up` method, but now with the FK name that you want it.In that moment is when you can change the FK name in the `Down` method:

```
 public override void Down()
 {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.SubEntities", "ParentEntity_id", "dbo.MainEntities");
        DropIndex("dbo.SubEntities", new[] { "ParentEntity_id" });
        DropTable("dbo.SubEntities");
        DropTable("dbo.MainEntities");
 }
```

Comment: Hello @Leonardo, Check the update section.I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your `SubEntity` class:

```
[ForeignKey("ParentEntity")]
public int ParentEntity_id { get; set; }

public virtual MainEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
```